# Copy contents of a directory to lots of other subdirectories

Tags: php, directory, duplication

I have a some template files organised like this in a directory:

```
index.php
preferences.xml
user.xml
```

I have also have subdirectory of this directory that contains a large number of folders (the exact number of folders can change a lot) which have outdated versions of the above template files:

```
randomfolder1
randomfolder20
randomfolder29
...
```

I would like to be able to copy the template files into all of these folders in the subdirectory, regardless of how many directories or template files there are. This is an example of what I would like in every folder:

```
randomfolder
- index.php
- preferences.xml
- user.xml
```

I have used this to copy the template files into ONE directory, but not all of them:

```
$cdire = 'GMXD/Users/firstdirectory';
mkdir($cdire);
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
recurse_copy('template',$cdire);
```

So how can you make this script copy all files in the template directory to all files in the subdirectory ?

Comment: And what is the specific issue / question?

Comment: What in specific are you having trouble with? Can you share your attempts and show us where you are stuck? Otherwise we have to guess what it is that needs be answered.

Comment: Question edited, is more specific now.